# $|x-y|<|y|/2 \Rightarrow |x|>|y|/2 ?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logic

Although I cannot think of any counter-examples where this fails, I cannot quite understand the intuition behind the result either. If two values are quite close to each other, then this implies that the absolute value of one of them is greater than half the absolute value of the other? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose $y > 0$. Then $\lvert x-y\rvert < \lvert y\rvert/2$ means $x \in (y/2, 3y/2)$. Similar for $y < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the triangle inequality. $|y|-|x| \leq |y - x | = |x - y| < \frac{|y|}{2}$. Rearrange to get the result.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks.